# Inner private method undefined while unit testing a public method - Jest & TypeScript

Tags: typescript, jestjs

I'm trying to unit test a public method that itself uses a private method.

Here is my class:

```
class MyService {    
  public publicMethod(): boolean { 
    return this.privateMethod();
  }
    
  private privateMethod(): boolean {
    return true;
  }
}

export default new MyService();
```

Here is my test:

```
describe('test', () => {
  const method = myService.publicMethod;
  it('Should return true', () => {
    expect(method()).toBe(true);
  });
});
```

Running this test leads to this TypeScript error:

```
● test › Should return true

    TypeError: Cannot read property 'privateMethod' of undefined

      xx | 
      xx |   public publicMethod(): boolean {
    > xx |     return this.privateMethod();
         |                 ^
      xx |   }
      xx | 
      xx |   private privateMethod(): boolean {
```

I've spent hours looking for a solution but can only find "workarounds".

Anyone encountered this problem before?
Thanks for your help.

Comment: how is `myService` created ?

Comment: you need to create the object first,

Comment: @TitianCernicova-Dragomir You comment lead me to the solution, I'll update my code above. I thought it would be a good idea to assign the test method to a const before using it (for reading purpose) but that was the problem. I would have not expected that. Thanks

Comment: The error is not related to TypeScript or Jest in any way. A JavaScript "method" is just a regular function. It becomes a method when it is called through an object. When it is called directly it does not have anything in `this`.

Answer (score 0):

Assigning the method to a const was the problem.

```
describe('test', () => {
  const method = myService.publicMethod;
  it('Should return true', () => {
    expect(method()).toBe(true);
  });
});
```

Here is the working test

```
describe('test', () => {
  it('Should return true', () => {
    expect(myService.publicMethod()).toBe(true);
  });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

you can try `jest.spyOn` for get implementation of private method

Example Class

```
export default class Calculator {
  private Sum(a: number, b: number): number {
    let c = a + b;
    return c;
  }
}
```

Test

```
const handleErrorSpy = jest.spyOn(Calculator.prototype, 'Sum');
const getSumImplementation = handleErrorSpy.getMockImplementation();

expect(getSumImplementation(1, 2)).toEqual(3);
```